# pivot function transformation pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df2

```
     date        ID     count
 0  2017-08-01   40      12
 1  2017-09-03   40      5
 2  2017-09-22   50      6
 3  2017-10-23   75      5
 4  2017-10-24   100     10
```

It should now be:
  where the count number of column ID is represented each month

```
  Index         40       50     75   100
  August        12       0      0    0
  September     5        6      0    0
  October       0        0      5    10
```

Here is the code:

```
df3= pd.DataFrame(df2, columns= ['date','ID','count'])
df3=df.pivot(index='date', columns='ID',values='count').reset_index().fillna(0)
print(df3)
df3.set_index('date').plot()
pyplot.show()
```

But I get this error:
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1c0521496a0

Comment: Here's an alt: `df.set_index([df.date.astype(str).str.rsplit('-', 1).str[0], 'ID'])['count'].unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: I tried this but I got this error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: I have edited the question with the 2nd dataframe index changing to months in words